# Find the coordinates of the vector in quadrant 4, in terms of $\sin(\theta)$ and $\cos(\theta)$. Assume the hypotenuse is equal to 1.

Tags: trigonometry

Find the coordinates of the vector in quadrant 4, in terms of $\sin(\theta)$ and $\cos(\theta)$. Assume the hypotenuse is equal to 1.

[image]

My solution:

$\sin(\theta) =$ opposite/hypotenuse $=$ opposite/1 = opposite

Since opposite is in the negative $y$ direction, $-\sin(\theta) =$ opposite.

$\cos(\theta) =$ adjacent/hypotenuse $=$ adjacent/1 $=$ adjacent.

Since adjacent is in the positive $x$ direction, $\cos(\theta) =$ adjacent

Therefore, the coordinates of the vector in quadrant 4 are $(cos(\theta), -\sin(\theta))$.

However, my solutions say the answer is $(\sin(\theta),-\cos(\theta))$. Why is my reasoning incorrect? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply take $\theta=0$ and you'll see that the solutions you were given are wrong. Yours seems good, but $\theta=0$ does not allow to check the sign of the sine; to do so, it's a good habit to take $\theta$ small: for small positive $\theta$, you see that the $y$ coordinate of the vector is negative, which is in accordance with what you found.

Though not a proof, this gives a very fast way of checking that the solutions you calculated is the right one.

Comment: @ThePointer Maybe in this case $(\cos (-\theta),\sin (-\theta))$?  Because the angle's being measured clockwise from the positive $x$-axis rather than counterclockwise.

Comment: @Mike I've created a new question to specifically address this. This is to avoid cluttering this one with additional questions that were not originally stated. Please refer to the following question. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1946031/find-the-coordinates-of-the-vector-in-quadrant-4-in-terms-of-sin-theta-and