# Find the coordinates of the vector in quadrant 4, in terms of $\sin(\theta)$ and $\cos(\theta)$. Assume the hypotenuse is equal to 1. #2

Tags: trigonometry

Find the coordinates of the vector in quadrant 4, in terms of $\sin(\theta)$ and $\cos(\theta)$. Assume the hypotenuse is equal to 1.

This question is related to the following question.

[Find the coordinates of the vector in quadrant 4, in terms of $\sin(\theta)$ and $\cos(\theta)$. Assume the hypotenuse is equal to 1.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1946014/find-the-coordinates-of-the-vector-in-quadrant-4-in-terms-of-sin-theta-and)

[image]

The method I used for calculating the coordinates in the previous question was incorrect. My solutions say the answer is $(\sin(\theta),-\cos(\theta))$.

What is a general method to find the coordinates for these types of questions? Thanks.

Comment: You are associating the wrong coordinate with the wrong trig values. Also, it's NOT clear whether your angle is positive or negative. If it's negative, the negative value for $y$ will naturally result from $\sin$ without any adjustments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A general method, as for any problem in general, is to start by writing what you know. Denote by $(x,y)$ the coordinates of the vector. You want to find $x$ and $y$. You know $\theta$ (assumed to be fixed, you don't need a real value) and $h$.

Even though it is not clear in your drawing, I assume that here $\theta<0$.
Then, $\sin(\theta)=y/h=y$ and $\cos(\theta)=x/h=x$. There's really nothing more than trivial trigonometry.

Had you considered $\theta >0$, you would have $\sin(\theta)=-y$. As I said in the answer to the linked question, the solution you provide is obviously wrong.

Comment: This is the exact same method I used in my previous question, which was incorrect. Yet, you're repeating the same method? I'm confused as to why my solution was incorrect?

Comment: What do you mean by considering $\theta > 0$?We have $\theta < 0$ in this case, so why would I consider $\theta > 0$?

Comment: It all depends on your convention. If for you $\theta$ is negative here, then it's fine. You might have wanted to consider only positive angles. Up to you!

Comment: @ThePointer Who said your solution was incorrect? (your solution = the one you calculated, not the one you were provided with). I specifically answer " this gives a very fast way of checking that **the solution you calculated is the right one**."

Comment: I realise that. I'm just asking why my solution was incorrect? I did everything as you described above, yet you said that I got the wrong answer.

Comment: @ThePointer Read again, I said the opposite.

Comment: Oh wow, you're right. Sorry, I must have assumed the worst and just misread!